# How to read and extract values from a binary file using python code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, binaryfiles, astronomy

I am relatively new to python. As part of my astronomy project work, I have to deal with binary files (which of course is again new to me). I was given a binary file and a python code which reads data from the binary file. I was then asked by my professor to understand how the code works on the binary file. I spent couple of days trying to figure out, but nothing helped. Can anyone here help me with the code?

```
# Read the binary opacity file
f = open(file, "r")

# read file dimension sizes
a = np.fromfile(f, dtype=np.int32, count=16)
NX, NY, NZ = a[1], a[4], a[7]


# read the time and time step
time, time_step = np.fromfile(f, dtype=np.float64, count=2)

# number of iterations
nite = np.fromfile(f, dtype=np.int32, count=1)

# radius array
trash = np.fromfile(f, dtype=np.float64, count=1)
rad = np.fromfile(f, dtype=np.float64, count=a[1])

# phi array
trash = np.fromfile(f, dtype=np.float64, count=1)
phi = np.fromfile(f, dtype=np.float64, count=a[4])

# close the file
f.close()
```

The binary file as far as I know contains several parameters (eg: radius, phi, sound speed, radiation energy) and its many values. The above code extract the values 2 parameters- radius and phi from the binary file. Both radius and phi have more than 100 values. The program works, but I am not able to understand how it works. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What exactly do you not understand?

Comment: Also, since most lines are calls to `np.fromfile()`, have you looked at [its documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromfile.html)?

Comment: @Asmus Yes I did, but nothing helped

Comment: @mkrieger1   I am not understanding how the code captures the value from the binary file. For eg, consider the 2 lines below #radius array. How do these lines gets the value of radius from the binary file ?

Comment: Hai, one thing that I understood while working with binary file is, the order/sequence in which the data is declared matters. For eg, in the above program, if 'b' was called (using np.fromfile) before 'a', then the values get exchanged, ie, the result that was actually displayed when calling 'a' now gets displayed when calling 'b'. Have I understood this correct ?

Answer (score 0):

The binary file is essentially just a long list of continuous data; you need to tell np.fromfile() both *where to look* and *what type of data* to expect. 
Perhaps it's easiest to understand if you create your own file:

```py
import numpy as np

with open('numpy_testfile', 'w+') as f:
    ## we create a "header" line, which collects the lengths of all relevant arrays
    ## you can then use this header line to tell np.fromfile() *how long* the arrays are
    dimensions=np.array([0,10,0,0,10,0,3,10],dtype=np.int32)
    dimensions.tofile(f) ## write to file

    a=np.arange(0,10,1) ## some fake data, length 10
    a.tofile(f) ## write to file
    print(a.dtype)

    b=np.arange(30,40,1) ## more fake data, length 10
    b.tofile(f) ## write to file
    print(b.dtype)

    ##  more interesting data, this time it's of type float, length 3
    c=np.array([3.14,4.22,55.0],dtype=np.float64) 
    c.tofile(f) ## write to file
    print(c.dtype)

    a.tofile(f) ## just for fun, let's write "a" again

with open('numpy_testfile', 'r+b') as f:
    ### what's important to know about this step is that 
    #   numpy is "seeking" the file automatically, i.e. it is considering 
    #   the first count=8, than the next count=10, and so on 
    #   as "continuous data"
    dim=np.fromfile(f,dtype=np.int32,count=8)
    print(dim) ## our header line: [ 0 10  0  0 10  0  3 10]
    a=np.fromfile(f,dtype=np.int64,count=dim[1])## read the dim[1]=10 numbers
    b=np.fromfile(f,dtype=np.int64,count=dim[4])## and the next 10
    ## now it's dim[6]=3, and the dtype is float 10
    c=np.fromfile(f,dtype=np.float64,count=dim[6] )#count=30)
    ## read "the rest", unspecified length, let's hope it's all int64 actually!
    d=np.fromfile(f,dtype=np.int64) 

print(a)
print(b)
print(c)
print(d)
```

**Addendum:** the [numpy documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromfile.html) is quite explicit when it comes to **discouraging the use** of `np.tofile()` and `np.fromfile()`:

> Do not rely on the combination of tofile and fromfile for data storage, as the binary files generated are are not platform independent. In particular, no byte-order or data-type information is saved. Data can be stored in the platform independent .npy format using save and load instead.

*Personal side note:* if you spent a couple of days to understand this code, don't feel discouraged of learning `python`; we all start somewhere. I'd suggest to be honest about the obstacles you've hit to your Professor (if this comes up in conversation), as she/he should be able to correctly assert "where you're at" when it comes to programming. :-)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I will keep in mind what you said. Just one more help, what does that line starting with " trash = ..." in the code I posted mean ?

Comment: @manubjayan well, I suppose it means it's literal *trash*, i.e. irrelevant, not needed information, that can be skipped/ignored. You still need to apply `np.fromfile(.. count=1)`, in order to seek/advance by "one".

Comment: Hai, one thing that I understood while working with binary file is, the order/sequence in which the data is declared matters. For eg, in the above program, if 'b' was called (using np.fromfile) before 'a', then the values get exchanged, ie, the result that was actually displayed when calling 'a' now gets displayed when calling 'b'. Have I understood this correct ?

Comment: @manubjayan yes, that's correct, but this will only work correctly if both `a` and `b` have an equal length and dtype. Consider a string: `aaabbbccdddde`; if I asked you to write an instruction how to separate this string by letter, you would likely end up with a statement like "the first three are a, the next three are b, the next two are c, …". That's essentially what the above code does, only that if I told you that "aaa" should be understood as *one continuous element "A"*, your instruction would have to change to "the first is **one** A, the next are three b,…" (that's what dtype infers)

Answer (score 0):

```
from astropy.io import ascii    
data = ascii.read('/directory/filename')
column1data = data[nameofcolumn1]
column2data = data[nameofcolumn2]
```

ect.
column1data is now an array of all the values under that header
I use this method to import SourceExtractor dat files which are in the ASCII format.
I believe this a more elegant way to import data from ascii files.